# Trigger Github action workflow only on changes in a path in a specific branch

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions

To prevent churn we have a version.yaml file which has e.g v0.0.0 in the dev branch

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths 
     - 'version.yaml'
```

I want to restrict this to only one branch i.e dev at the moment as a pr is done to the next branch it triggers the job again when it should only run once in dev .Is there a way to restrict it to branch

It reads the version.yaml file changes and also checks it on the dev branch then only it gets triggered

Comment: Sounds like you could use `on.push.branches`?

Comment: Also notice that you're missing a colon after `paths`

Comment: Thanks for the link when branch and path is put it checks both the conditions as an and condition which is good to know